# Passing value of select menu to variable

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I am using the following procedure to get information from drop down menu:

```
$('select[name=status]').change(function(){ 
selectstatus = $("select[name=status]").val();
```

Currently it is getting information from the drop down menu with name=status. In case if I have more than one drop down menus with that name the script is not working correctly. It is working only for the first select menu that appears and for the rest is not selecting anything inside the variable selectstatus, how to modify the code that it will work with any select menu it doesn't matter what name it have.

```
  <?php echo "<select name='status' id='$ids' idc='$idc'>" ?>
  <option value="">Opcion:</option>
  <option value="aprobado">Aprobado</option>
  <option value="cupolleno">Cupo Lleno</option>
  <option value="cancelado">Curso Cancelado</option>
  <option value="noacion">No Acion</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this)`

```
$('select[name=status]').change(function(){ 
selectstatus = $(this).val();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

With `$(this)`:

```
selectstatus = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a class to make it easy to target every select that you want this handler on.

```
<?php echo "<select name='status' class='getstatus' id='$ids' idc='$idc'>" ?>
<option value="">Opcion:</option>
<option value="aprobado">Aprobado</option>
<option value="cupolleno">Cupo Lleno</option>
<option value="cancelado">Curso Cancelado</option>
<option value="noacion">No Acion</option>
</select>
```

Then use the class name as the selector. Use $(this) to reference the select that fired the change event.

```
$('.getstatus').change(function(){ 
var selectstatus = $(this).val();
});
```